# Parameterized Test on Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I saw when I uploaded my tests on Xamarin Test Cloud that there is a option called --test-params.

So my questions are :

1) How can I use params defined in this option on Xamarin Test Cloud and how can I setUp my test class for use these ?

2) Is there a way to run all test which I executed last time directly on Xamarin Test Cloud Interface ?

Comment: Are you using Calabash, Xamarin.UITest, or Appium as your testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

To 1) The test-params is nothing you can use within your tests. As far as I have used them, they are to configure additional settings. For an Android test you can set `--test-params screencapture:true`, which will record your tests.

To 2) There is currently no way to simply re-run a test from the website again. Even so it is on the feature-wish-list.